# Prevent Express.js 4.x from showing exception details to end user

Tags: node.js

I am currently writing a site in NodeJS, using Express as the routing agent. My code is not perfect, and sometimes there are problems that cause express to throw exceptions, which, if the errors occur whilst the user is making a request, and sent to and seen by the user. This poses a security risk for me, and I was wondering if there was a way that I can catch these errors, and send a custom 500 error page, instead of showing the stack trace. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on mobile right now, and I'll update this answer if you need any clarifications very soon, but if you're using express-generator, the generated template includes an error handler at the bottom of app.js that does not pass the stack trace to the error page. Check that out. You can get that one to trigger by setting an environment variable called `NODE_ENV` to `production` if you're using everything default. Otherwise, you can simply comment out or modify the first error handler.

Comment: I'm not using the express generator, but I'll spin one up and check out the code

Comment: I was able to use express-generator to find the code, thanks for your help!